# RSelenium - java.lang.IllegalStateException in R

Tags: r, webdriver

I'm trying to open the remote driver using `z$open()` in R studio and the following error occurs

```
library(RSelenium)
checkForServer()     
startServer()    
z <-remoteDriver()    
z$open()

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

I'm using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21), RStudio (0.99.903), Java version 1.8.0_111, Firefox version 47.0.1,RSelenium version 1.4.0

Comment: What version of RSelenium and selenium server?

Comment: RSelenium version 1.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using firefox version 47.0.1 .so it working only when **selenium-server-** **standalone-2.53.1.jar** .so,download it in Rselenium package bin folder.don't use checkForserver() in code